# convert ETS to UTC for entire year from txt file

Tags: python

I am relatively new to programming in python, and have been stuck on this problem for a while and just cannot seem to find a solution.  I need to convert times from a txt file that are in EST/EDT to UTC, and since its the whole year I need to consider daylight savings.

2014 01 01 00    1751.9

2014 01 01 01    1681.5

2014 01 01 02    1647.8

2014 01 01 03    1629.2

2014 01 01 04    1623.6

2014 01 01 05    1644.3

My txt file has the date and time along with electrical load data for a single turbine for each day. The fifth column of data represents the hour of each day in EST/EDT.  I need to convert all hours for everyday to UTC. Is there a specific way to do this?

So far I  have the following, but I only know how to input one specific time.

```
East_Coast = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
Current = datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-01-01 0:0:0", "%Y-%m-%d %H:% M:%    S") 
East_Coast_dt = East_Coast.localize(Current, is_dst=None)
utc_dt = East_Coast_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)

print utc_dt
```

Is there anyway to incorporate the entire text file for all hours? I have only found examples for one specific time.